# constructing a multi-dimensional array of form inputs

Tags: php, arrays

PHP supports:

```
<input type=text name=array[]>
```

...and all values are just posted in that array.  I want to do the same for a multidimensional? array, however I am getting slightly lost in trying to extract data.

I have a set of questions, most have one answer (radio buttons) however some are multi-response (checkboxes). I want to be able to store all answers in one multidimensional array so it may appear like this:

question 1 | answer | 
question 2 | answer | 
question 3 | answer | 
question 3 | answer | 
question 3 | answer | 
question 4 | answer |

So, I am doing this:

```
<input name="response['q1'][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response['q2'][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response['q3'][]" type=text value=''>
<input name="response['q3'][]" type=text value=''>
```

Now how can I go about extracting this data for storing into my mysql db. Ive been playing around with a foreach, however when it is the case there is more than one answer for a question (q3 lets say) I can't get that data in my loop.

Comment: like this : "response[$question_id][$response_id]" makes a lot easier parsing

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving the quotes away (name="response[q3][]") and then loop using `foreach($_POST['response']['q3'] as $key => $value) { echo $value."\n"; }`

```
foreach($_POST['response'] as $question => $answer) {
  if(count($answer) > 1) {
    foreach($answer as $key => $value) {
      //loop your multiple answers here
    }
  } elseif(count($answer) == 1 {
     // 1 answer found for $_POST['response'][ $question ];
  } else {
    // no answer found.. (perhaps $_POST['response'][ $key ] is a value and no array.
  }
}
```

I guess this is what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry I think I mislead, that code I've shown is just an example, to show what the scenario may actually be with my actual code. I don't know which questions will have multiple answers. So I guess what I am trying to do is have the q id as a value along with the actual text answer, rather than a key.

Comment: if it has multiple than count($_POST['response']['q3']) would be larger than 1. Otherwise it has 1 (or 0) answers.. see my edit above.